# MySQL query to fetch row count of hourly records inserted and max record per minute in that hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table with following fields

```
id CreatedOn(yyyymmddhhmmss)           Channel_id

10 20200617160916792                      13

11 20200617160919792                      13
 
12 20200617170919792                      13

13 20200617170919792                      13

14 20200617160920212                      14
```

I need a query to check how many total records are inserted in particular hour and maximum records per minutes in that hour based on channel Id. For example if 100 record are inserted at 15:00-16:00 then what is maximum record insert per minutes. Please help me creating a query to find the required solution

I have run this query, Although it is given me total record per hour but I also want to know how maximum are inserted per min.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%H:00') as hours,
       count(CreatedOn) as total_hit, channel_id
  FROM tbl_transaction_flow where DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%Y-%m-%d')  = DATE(NOW())
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00'),channel_id;
```

Need output as

```
hours      total_hits   channel_id    max_hit_per_minutes
16:00       100           13           20
17:00       10            13            1
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MYSQL version is 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%H:%i') as hours_minutes,
                     COUNT(CreatedOn) as hits_per_minute, 
                     Channel_id
              FROM tbl_transaction_flow 
              WHERE DATE(CreatedOn) = /* CURRENT_DATE */ '2020-06-17'
              GROUP BY hours_minutes, Channel_id )
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONCAT(LEFT(hours_minutes, 2), ':00') hours,
       Channel_id,
       SUM(hits_per_minute) OVER win hits_per_hour,
       MAX(hits_per_minute) OVER win max_hits_per_minute
FROM cte
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY Channel_id, LEFT(hours_minutes, 2));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2635180061e45e761864ff7b4b018f3

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(hours_minutes, 2), ':00') hours,
       Channel_id,
       SUM(hits_per_minute) hits_per_hour,
       MAX(hits_per_minute) max_hits_per_minute
FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%H:%i') as hours_minutes,
              COUNT(CreatedOn) as hits_per_minute, 
              Channel_id
       FROM tbl_transaction_flow 
       WHERE DATE(CreatedOn) = /* CURRENT_DATE */ '2020-06-17'
       GROUP BY hours_minutes, Channel_id ) per_minute_data
GROUP BY hours, Channel_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d7f14899377fc491efb4ca8635e4a4a6

Comment: @akina I am also working for this solution. What will be this query in mysql 5.7

Comment: @im5an Code for 5.6+ added.

Comment: @akina I need to modify this query to get records based on total hit_per_hour and max hit per second instead of per minute. Can you pls help me

Comment: @HaiderAli Add according condition into HAVING clause.

Comment: @HaiderAli https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ba619ac05ec20a463d110f319d5dbfd9

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT date_format(created_at,'%H %p') AS hour, count(*) AS total_record 
    FROM users 
   WHERE CAST(created_at AS DATE) ="2021-12-15" 
GROUP BY date_format(created_at,'%H %p')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it